# In Which Position To Place Adjective In Infinitive Form Of It

Tags: verbs, infinitives

I Want to know when we use infinitive verb as an adjective what is the position of the to-infinity adjective as i noticed in this url examples it always use the last postilion https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/infinitive_form.htm

Give him an ornament **to polish**.

(The infinitive modifies ornament. This means it is functioning as an adjective.)

I need a volunteer **to take the minutes**.
(The infinitive modifies volunteer. This means it is functioning as an adjective.)

Comment: Your own source gives you the answer: **An infinitive that acts as an adjective usually appears immediately after the noun it is modifying.** One might construct a sentence that's an exception to this rule, as in **There's a call coming through to answer**. But in practice these would be few and far between.

Answer (score 1):

> *Give him an ornament* [*to polish*].
>
> *I need a volunteer* [*to take the minutes*].

The bracketed elements are not adjectives: they are infinitival relative clauses functioning as **modifier** of "ornament" and "volunteer". Relative clauses never precede but always follow the noun or nominal that they modify: we can't say *"Give him a to polish ornament".

Note that not everything that modifies a noun is an adjective!

Comment: but in the url it was mentioned as an adjective does they are incorrect                                                              Give him an ornament to polish.
(The infinitive modifies ornament. This means it is functioning as an adjective.)

Comment: @TradeNiveshInvestmentAdviso **No!** Adjective is a word class (part of speech). Modifier is a function, like subject, object etc. GrammarMonster is a joke. It's the worst possible resource. Everything it says is wrong. – BillJ 4 mins ago   Edit   Delete

Comment: ok thanks for the information