# What is Defining And Non Defining Relative Clauses

Tags: infinitives, relative-clauses

I am reading an article on infinitive verbs and there is a sentence and there mention this:

> Give him an ornament **to polish**

here they mention that the **to polish** is used as an to-infinite adjective but is that really an adjective or a clause here is the link of the article (https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/infinitive_form.htm)

Comment: It is not an adjective. "To polish" is an infinitival relative clause that functions as a post-modifier.

Comment: ok means that website is showing incorrect information?

Comment: You have already asked this question, here: [link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/232993/in-which-position-to-place-adjective-in-infinitive-form-of-it/233000?noredirect=1#comment442805_233000). Why are you asking the same question again?